# Что значить hwnd unused?

Tags: c++, winapi

В winapi при создании кнопок происходит исключение Access violation reading location и в дебаггере пишет, что hWnd unused=???. Что это значит?

Создаю кнопки:

```
case WM_CREATE: // Сообщение приходит при создании окна
    easyLevel = CreateWindow("button", "Легкий", WS_CHILD, 420, 250, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    middleLevel = CreateWindow("button", "Средний", WS_CHILD, 420, 290, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)2, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    hardLevel = CreateWindow("button", "Сложный", WS_CHILD, 420, 330, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)3, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

    buttonPlay = CreateWindow("button", "Играть!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 420, 250, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)100, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    buttonExit = CreateWindow("button", "Выход", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 420, 300, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)101, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    break;
```

Генерация поля для игры в сапер. Если кнопка в поле является бомбой, то написать в ней "b".

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
        ShowWindow(easyLevel, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(middleLevel, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(hardLevel, SW_HIDE);
        Field myField = Field(10, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < myField.getSizeX(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myField.getSizeY(); j++) {
                if (myField.getField()[i][j].isBomb()) {
                    myField.getField()[i][j].setButton(CreateWindow("button", "b", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 370 + j * 25, 250 + i * 25, 25, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)(i + j + 1), ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL));
                }
                else {
                    myField.getField()[i][j].setButton(CreateWindow("button", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 370 + j * 25, 250 + i * 25, 25, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)(i + j + 1), ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL)); // место, где возникает ошибка
                }
                UpdateWindow(myField.getField()[i][j].getButton());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы нужен. Иначе гадать можно долго...

Comment: Оказывается, любой объект HWND не могу прочитать.

Answer (score 2):

Это значит что переменная `hWnd` находится в памяти, которую нельзя прочитать, а поле `unused` - это внутренности типа `HWND`, про них знать не надо.